# executing python script passed to aws user data through terraform as a file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, terraform

The Problem:
I'm trying to pass a dynamically created python script to an AWS launch_config created with terraform. The script appears in the user data of the instance but doesn't execute. I'm not sure why all of the guides I read about passing scripts through user data say that this should work.

I know the script shows up because I can curl aws user data and it will be there, but it never executed.

What am I missing?

The dynamically created python:

```
user_data_ins = ('''export CLOUD_ENVIRONMENT=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_MONITOR_BUCKET=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_APP=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_STACK=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_CLUSTER=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_AUTO_SCALE_GROUP=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_LAUNCH_CONFIG=%s\n
                    export EC2_REGION=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_DEV_PHASE=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_REVISION=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_DOMAIN=%s\n
                    export SG_GROUP=%s\n''' % (cloud_environment,
                                                cluster_monitor_bucket,
                                                cluster_name,
                                                cloud_stack,
                                                cloud_cluster,
                                                cloud_auto_scale_group,
                                                cloud_launch_config,
                                                provider_region,
                                                cloud_dev_phase,
                                                cloud_revision,
                                                cloud_domain,
                                                export_env_sg_name))



user_data_ins = ('''
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess
import time
import uuid


def shell_command_execute(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    print output
    return output

repo = "%s"
playbook = "%s"


echo_bash_profile = "echo " + %s + " >> ~/.bash_profile"
shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile)

var_user_data = "%s"

for varb in var_user_data.split('|'):
    echo_bash_profile_passed = "echo " + varb  + " >> ~/.bash_profile"
    shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile_passed)

command = 'git clone ' + repo
shell_command_execute(command)

folder = repo.split('/')[4].replace('.git','')
#https://github.com/zukeru/vision_provis.git
execute_playbook = ('ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local' +  '/' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/' + folder + '/' + playbook >> ansible.log')
print execute_playbook
shell_command_execute(execute_playbook)
''' % (str(repo), str(playbook),str(user_data_ins), str(in_user_data)))

text_file = open("user-data.py", "wa")
text_file.write(user_data_ins)    
text_file.close()    
lc_user_data = '${file("%s/user-data.py")}' %wd
```

The Whole Script:

```
import argparse
import subprocess
import sys
import boto.ec2
import random
import multiprocessing
import time
import collections
import os
import uuid
import base64

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()    
parser.add_argument('--secret_key', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--wd', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--access_key', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--provider-region', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--autoscale_group', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--min_size', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--max_size', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--asg_name', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--azs', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--env', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--desired_size', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--force_delete', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--hc_type', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--hc_period', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--lc_name', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--lc_image_id', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--lc_instance_type', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--lc_iam_instance_profile', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--lc_key_name', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--in_user_data', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--lc_public_ip', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--launch_config', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--tags', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--block_devices', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--asg_vpc_ident', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--cloud_stack', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--cloud_environment', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--cloud_domain', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--cluster_monitor_bucket', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--cloud_cluster', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--cloud_auto_scale_group', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--cloud_launch_config', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--cloud_dev_phase', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--cloud_revision', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--role', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--security_groups', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--sg_tag', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--vpc_id', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--repo', help='', required=False)
parser.add_argument('--playbook', help='', required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()
#secret_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_KEY')
#access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY')
sg_tag = args.sg_tag
secret_key = args.secret_key
access_key = args.access_key
vpc_id = args.vpc_id
provider_region = args.provider_region
security_groups = args.security_groups
cloud_stack = args.cloud_stack 
cloud_environment = args.cloud_environment
cloud_domain = args.cloud_domain
cluster_monitor_bucket = args.cluster_monitor_bucket
cloud_cluster =  args.cloud_cluster
cloud_auto_scale_group = args.cloud_auto_scale_group
cloud_launch_config = args.cloud_launch_config
cloud_dev_phase = args.cloud_dev_phase
cloud_revision = args.cloud_revision
role = args.role
env_name = args.env
#asg arguments
min_size = args.min_size
max_size = args.max_size
desired_size = args.desired_size
azs = args.azs
asg_name = args.asg_name
force_delete = args.force_delete
tags = args.tags
hc_type = args.hc_type
hc_period = args.hc_period
az_list = args.azs
vpc_zone_ident = args.asg_vpc_ident

#launch configuration values
lc_name = args.lc_name
lc_image_id = args.lc_image_id
lc_instance_type = args.lc_instance_type
lc_iam_instance_profile = args.lc_iam_instance_profile
lc_key_name = args.lc_key_name
in_user_data = args.in_user_data
lc_public_ip = args.lc_public_ip
block_devices = args.block_devices
security_group_name = []
wd = args.wd
playbook = args.playbook
repo = args.repo


def build_lc(lc_name, lc_name2, lc_image_id, lc_instance_type, lc_public_ip, lc_security_groups, lc_iam_instance_profile, lc_user_data, lc_key_name,block_device_mapping):
    launch_config_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
    if lc_name:
        launch_config_dict['lcname'] = lc_name
    if lc_name2:
        launch_config_dict['name'] = lc_name2
    if lc_image_id:
        launch_config_dict['image_id'] = lc_image_id
    if lc_instance_type:
        launch_config_dict['instance_type'] = lc_instance_type

    launch_config_dict['associate_public_ip_address'] = 'True'

    if lc_security_groups:
        launch_config_dict['security_groups'] = str(lc_security_groups).replace("'",'"')
    if lc_iam_instance_profile:
        launch_config_dict['iam_instance_profile'] = lc_iam_instance_profile
    if lc_user_data:
        launch_config_dict['user_data'] = lc_user_data
    if lc_key_name:
        launch_config_dict['key_name'] = lc_key_name
    if block_device_mapping:
        launch_config_dict['block_device'] = block_device_mapping


    lc_string = '\nresource "aws_launch_configuration" "%s" {\n' % launch_config_dict['lcname']

    for key, value in launch_config_dict.iteritems():
        if value != None:
            if key == 'lcname':
                continue
            if key != 'block_device':
                if key != 'security_groups':
                    lc_string = lc_string + '        %s="%s"\n' % (key, value)
                else:
                    lc_string = lc_string + '        %s=%s\n' % (key, value)
            else:
                lc_string = lc_string + '        %s\n' % (value)
    lc_string = lc_string + '\n    }'
    return lc_string

def build_tags(tags):
    built_tags = ''
    tags = tags.split(',')
    for tag in tags:
        if len(tag) > 5:
            values = tag.split(':')
            built_tags = built_tags + """
            tag {
                key = "%s"
                value = "%s"
                propagate_at_launch = %s
                }                                   
            """ % (values[0],values[1],values[2])
    return built_tags

def build_block_devices(block_devices):

    built_devices = ''
    block_devices = block_devices.split(',')
    for device in block_devices:
        if len(device) > 6:
            values = device.split(':')
            built_devices = built_devices + '''
                ebs_block_device{
                    device_name = "%s"
                    volume_type = "%s"
                    volume_size = %s
                    delete_on_termination = %s
                    iops = %s
                }
            ''' % (values[0].split('=')[1],values[1].split('=')[1],values[2].split('=')[1],values[3].split('=')[1],values[4].split('=')[1])
    return built_devices

def build_az_list(azs):
    az_list = []
    az_values = azs.split(',')
    for az in az_values:
        az_list.append('%s' % az)
    return az_list

def build_rules(rules):
    build_string = ''
    for rule in rules.split(':'):
        name = rule.split('=')[0]
        if len(rule) > 10:
            build_string = build_string + '''
                    %s {
                        from_port = %s
                        to_port = %s
                        protocol = "%s"
                        %s = %s
                        }
                        ''' % (name, 
                               rule.split('=')[1].split(';')[0].split('|')[1], 
                               rule.split('=')[1].split(';')[1].split('|')[1], 
                               rule.split('=')[1].split(';')[2].split('|')[1], 
                               rule.split('=')[1].split(';')[3].split('|')[0],
                               rule.split('=')[1].split(';')[3].split('|')[1])
    return build_string

def build_security_group(security_groups,vpc_id, cluster_name, sg_tag):
    security_group = ''
    flag = False
    for group in security_groups.split(','):
        if len(group) > 6:
            if 'name' in str(group):
                conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2',aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
                rs = conn.get_all_security_groups()
                check_name = cluster_name.split('-')
                check_name = check_name[0]+'-'+check_name[1]+'-'+check_name[2]
                check_name = str(check_name)
                sg_length = len(rs)
                for index, item in enumerate(rs):
                    item_ret = str(item)
                    if check_name in item_ret:
                        name = item_ret.replace('SecurityGroup:', '')
                        name2 = item_ret.replace('SecurityGroup:', '')
                        security_group_name.append(str(item.id))
                        flag = True
                        break
                    else:
                        if not security_group_name and index == (sg_length - 1):
                            name = cluster_name
                            name2 = cluster_name
                            security_group_name.append("${aws_security_group.%s.id}" % name)
                            break

                description = group.split(':')[1].split('=')[1]
                rules = group.split('!')[1]
                rules = build_rules(rules)
                if vpc_id != '0':
                    security_group = security_group + '''
                    resource "aws_security_group" "%s" {
                        name = "%s"
                        vpc_id = "%s"
                        description = "%s"
                        %s
                    }''' % (name, name2,vpc_id, description, rules) 
                else:
                    security_group = security_group + '''
                    resource "aws_security_group" "%s" {
                        name = "%s"
                        description = "%s"
                        %s
                    }''' % (name, name2, description, rules)   
            else:
                break   
    return_list = (security_group,security_group_name, flag, name)    
    return return_list 

#Dynamically builds ASG, and won't include values  if they dont exist. Need to do errors when its required.
def build_asg(**kwargs):
    asg_string = '\nresource "aws_autoscaling_group" "%s" {\n' % kwargs['asgname']
    order_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
    if kwargs['name']:
        order_dict['name'] = kwargs['name']
    if kwargs['availability_zones']:
        order_dict['availability_zones'] = str(kwargs['availability_zones']).replace("'",'"')
    if kwargs['max_size']:
        order_dict['max_size'] = kwargs['max_size']
    else:
        order_dict['max_size'] = 1
    if kwargs['min_size']:
        order_dict['min_size'] = kwargs['min_size']
    else:
        order_dict['min_size'] = 1
    if kwargs['launch_configuration']:
        order_dict['launch_configuration'] = kwargs['launch_configuration']
    if kwargs['health_check_grace_period']:
        order_dict['health_check_grace_period'] = kwargs['health_check_grace_period']
    if kwargs['health_check_type']:
        order_dict['health_check_type'] = kwargs['health_check_type']
    if kwargs['desired_capacity']:
        order_dict['desired_capacity'] = kwargs['desired_capacity']
    if kwargs['force_delete']:
        order_dict['force_delete'] = kwargs['force_delete']
    if kwargs['vpc_zone_identifier']: 
        order_dict['vpc_zone_identifier'] = kwargs['vpc_zone_identifier']
    if kwargs['built_tags']: 
        order_dict['built_tags'] = kwargs['built_tags']

    for key, value in order_dict.iteritems():
        if value != None:
            if key == 'asgname':
                continue
            if key != 'built_tags':
                if key != 'force_delete' and key != 'health_check_grace_period' and key != 'min_size' and key != 'max_size' and key != 'desired_capacity' and key != 'availability_zones' and key != 'vpc_zone_identifier':
                    asg_string = asg_string + '        %s = "%s"\n' % (key, value)
                else:
                    asg_string = asg_string + '        %s = %s\n' % (key, value)
            else:
                asg_string = asg_string + '        %s\n' % (value)
    asg_string = asg_string + '\n    }'
    return asg_string

def get_a_uuid():
    r_uuid = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes)
    return r_uuid.replace('=', '')

uuid = str(get_a_uuid())
asg_name = sg_tag + '-' + asg_name + '-' + env_name + '-' + '-' + uuid[:8]
cluster_name = asg_name
security_groups = security_groups.replace(' ', '')
security_groups = build_security_group(security_groups,vpc_id, cluster_name, sg_tag)
security_group_name = security_groups[1]
export_env_sg_name = security_groups[3]
security_groups = security_groups[0]
security_flag = security_groups[2]


if security_flag == True:
    lc_security_groups = security_group_name[0]
    lc_security_groups = '["%s"],' % lc_security_groups
else:
    lc_security_groups = security_group_name

az_list = build_az_list(azs)
block_devices = block_devices.replace(' ', '')
block_device_mapping = build_block_devices(block_devices)

constant_tag = 'ClusterName:%s:true ' % cluster_name

if tags:
    built_tags = build_tags(tags)
else:
    built_tags = constant_tag


user_data_ins = ('''export CLOUD_ENVIRONMENT=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_MONITOR_BUCKET=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_APP=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_STACK=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_CLUSTER=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_AUTO_SCALE_GROUP=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_LAUNCH_CONFIG=%s\n
                    export EC2_REGION=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_DEV_PHASE=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_REVISION=%s\n
                    export CLOUD_DOMAIN=%s\n
                    export SG_GROUP=%s\n''' % (cloud_environment,
                                                cluster_monitor_bucket,
                                                cluster_name,
                                                cloud_stack,
                                                cloud_cluster,
                                                cloud_auto_scale_group,
                                                cloud_launch_config,
                                                provider_region,
                                                cloud_dev_phase,
                                                cloud_revision,
                                                cloud_domain,
                                                export_env_sg_name))



user_data_ins = ('''
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess
import time
import uuid


def shell_command_execute(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    print output
    return output

repo = "%s"
playbook = "%s"


echo_bash_profile = "echo " + %s + " >> ~/.bash_profile"
shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile)

var_user_data = "%s"

for varb in var_user_data.split('|'):
    echo_bash_profile_passed = "echo " + varb  + " >> ~/.bash_profile"
    shell_command_execute(echo_bash_profile_passed)

command = 'git clone ' + repo
shell_command_execute(command)

folder = repo.split('/')[4].replace('.git','')
#https://github.com/zukeru/vision_provis.git
execute_playbook = ('ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local' +  '/' + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/' + folder + '/' + playbook >> ansible.log')
print execute_playbook
shell_command_execute(execute_playbook)
''' % (str(repo), str(playbook),str(user_data_ins), str(in_user_data)))

text_file = open("user-data.py", "wa")
text_file.write(user_data_ins)    
text_file.close()    
lc_user_data = '${file("%s/user-data.py")}' %wd

launch_config_variable = "${aws_launch_configuration.%s.id}" % cluster_name

launch_configuration = build_lc(cluster_name,cluster_name, lc_image_id, lc_instance_type, lc_public_ip, lc_security_groups, lc_iam_instance_profile, lc_user_data, lc_key_name,block_device_mapping)

autoscale_group = build_asg(built_tags = built_tags if built_tags else None,
                              asgname = asg_name, 
                              availability_zones = az_list, 
                              name = asg_name, 
                              max_size = max_size, 
                              min_size = min_size, 
                              launch_configuration = launch_config_variable, 
                              health_check_grace_period = hc_period if hc_period else None, 
                              health_check_type = hc_type if hc_type else None, 
                              desired_capacity = desired_size if desired_size else None, 
                              force_delete = force_delete if force_delete else None,
                              vpc_zone_identifier = vpc_zone_ident if vpc_zone_ident else None
                              )   

provider = """
        provider "aws" {
            access_key = "%s"
            secret_key = "%s"
            region = "%s"
        }
""" % (access_key, secret_key, provider_region)

text_file = open("Output.tf", "wa")
text_file.write(provider)

if security_flag == True:
    print 'nada'
else:
    text_file.write(security_groups)

text_file.write(launch_configuration)
text_file.write(autoscale_group)
text_file.close()
```

as per

I have base64 encoded the script as well [EC2 instance loads my user-data script but doesn't run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149144/ec2-instance-loads-my-user-data-script-but-doesnt-run-it)

but it still doesnt work.

```
encoded = base64.b64encode(user_data_ins)
text_file.write(encoded)    
text_file.close()    
lc_user_data = '${file("%s/user-data.py")}' %wd

curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
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
```

Comment: I see that your scripts are created but never executed. "user-data.py" should be ran by using "python user-data.py" after you run this script. You can do an os.system, or Popen.... within this script to run them

Comment: @FirebladeDan user-data.py is aws userdata passed to be executed on instance launch. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149144/ec2-instance-loads-my-user-data-script-but-doesnt-run-it for reference. I've tried base64 encoding the code and passing it as well but still doesnt execute.

Comment: Rather than inline the entire script in userdata, it might be better to store the script in S3, give the EC2 instance an IAM role that allows the instance to download the script from S3, and then download & execute it from userdata. Also, for the purpose of debugging this, start with a very simple script.

Comment: the script is built via vars that are passed to the terraform script I guess I could do that. I just wanted to know if the process is off?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is, you

1. create a program the you want to run during the initialisation of ec2
2. use a launch template where you define security group, user data file etc.
3. cloudInit handles it, you can send a file, then use another program to run it.

If you do not want to use launch template, fine, but you have to send the file first, then run it. I use terraform to create launch templates, then use other ways to create ec2.